# How to post images in LinkedIn groups using selenium and python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, linkedin-api, browser-automation

I am trying to post image in LinkedIn groups using selenium and python. So far I have been able to post tests only. I tried to upload images to but image is skipped. Neither I get some errors, only the text is posted.

Here is the link to [my complete code](https://pastebin.com/xqFzG6Rb).

```
def postImageInGroup(driver, group_url, title, body, image):
    driver.get(group_url)

    WebDriverWait(driver, 100)

    driver.find_element_by_name('title').click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 100)

    driver.find_element_by_name('title').send_keys(title)
    driver.find_element_by_name('body').send_keys(body)

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/2);")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 200)

    driver.find_element_by_name('file_upload').send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
    driver.find_element_by_name('file_upload').send_keys(image)

    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 200).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'action-submit')))
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('action-submit').click()
```